# how to get All audio Files from storage in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to make audio player with lyrics in xamarin forms of PCL. I am new to xamarin.forms so anyone help me how to fetch all audio files from storage in android as well iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to come up with this, although the algorithm is still being tested.

```
public IList<string> RootDirectory()
        {
            var Pathlist = new List<string>(); 
            try
            {
                var temp = new List<string>();
                Pathlist.Add(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath);
                Pathlist.Add(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath);
                Pathlist.Add(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic).AbsolutePath);
                foreach(var path in Pathlist)
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        temp.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList());
                    }
                }
                Pathlist.AddRange(temp);
                return Pathlist;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }      
        }

public IList<string> GetFiles()
        {
            var files = new List<string>();
            foreach(var dir in RootDirectory())
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(dir))
                {
                    var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir).ToList<string>();
                    file.ForEach(f => { if (f.EndsWith("mp3")) files.Add(f); });
                }  
            }
            return files;
        }
```

Comment: This is an implementation for android, use dependency service to call the respective methods from your PCL.